# An exception error occurred when building

Tags: flutter, dart

This error has appeared after using the color scheme property
for the primary and the secondary properties, I just need these two properties so it caused an error for finding null properties for the other scheme properties

```
 Exception caught by widgets library 
The following assertion was thrown building BMICalculator(dirty):
'package:flutter/src/material/color_scheme.dart': Failed assertion: line 118 pos 15: 'brightness != null': is not true.\
```

and here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(BMICalculator());

  class BMICalculator extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
           colorScheme: ColorScheme(
            primary: Colors.purple,
          secondary: Colors.red,
          ),
      ) ,
      home: InputPage(),
    );
  }
}

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),


        //  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Body Text'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your constructor for `ColorScheme` is missing a few required parameters, one of which is `brightness`.

You must ensure all the parameters marked with `required` on [this page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme/ColorScheme.html) are provided to your `ColorScheme` constructor.